# Clang warning on global destructor

Tags: c++, clang

Consider the following

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <string>
class A {
  std::string s;
};
static A a;
int main() {}
```

Using `clang++ main.cpp -Wglobal-constructors` to compile, I get the following warning

```
main.cpp:6:10: warning: declaration requires a global destructor [-Wglobal-constructors]
```

My questions are:

1. What does this warning mean and why does it happen.
2. How to resolve this warning.

Edit:
I tried to add a destructor `~A()` but this warning is still there.

Comment: The question marked as a dupe is referring to a different warning...